# Raspberry Pi and TLC5615 DAC

Tags: spi, raspberry-pi, dac

Currently I'm working in a project in which I need to programmatically control 2 currents from 0 to 1 Amp. My plan is to use two DACs controlled by a Raspberry Pi. My idea was to use the MCP4725 but this DAC wasn't available in my city, so my backup plan is to use the TLC5615. However, I'm not sure if this has I2C and if I can control two of these DACs at the same time using SPI.

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Answer (score 1):

There is no I2C interface in TLC5615 DAC. It has interface that supports SPI, QSPI and Microwire. Raspberry Pi has SPI, so you can use it.

You can connect more than 1 SPI slave to one SPI master.

To select device to communicate with - use CS pin. It is Chip Select pin. You will have to use SPI and 2 GPIO on Raspberry Pi to manipulate CS pins on both SPI slaves.

Answer (score 0):

The DAC does not support I2C.  It requires clock, data, and chip select inputs.  If the controller does not support multiple chip select lines in hardware, then you will have to use GPIO to drive the chip select lines.  Select a DAC, write to it, then deselect it.  Repeat for the other DAC.